# Deepcopying map containing pointer to structure

Tags: arrays, go

I currently have a map which is as follows

```
licFeatureMem              = make(map[string][]*common.Feature)
```

I need to make a copy of the map to pass into some function which modified the same so that i don't lose the original copy

```
modFeatureMem := make(map[string][]*common.Feature)
        for key, lst := range licFeatureMem {
            var newFtLst []*common.Feature
            for _, info := range lst {
                newFtLst = append(newFtLst, info)
            }
            modFeatureMem[key] = &newFtLst
        }
```

What is see is when `modFeatureMem` is modified, original `licFeatureMem` also gets modified.  Can someone please help me on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The copied map has the same pointers to the `common.Feature` instances the original map has. Any modification to `common.Feature` will be visible on both maps. To get a truly deep copy, you have to copy those objects as well:

```
for key, lst := range licFeatureMem {
            var newFtLst []*common.Feature
            for _, info := range lst {
                newInfo:=*info
                newFtLst = append(newFtLst, &newInfo)
            }
            modFeatureMem[key] = &newFtLst
        }
```